# Calculate the number of digits in a product of large numbers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I'm looking for a method that can calculate the number of digits in a product of several large numbers. For example, calculate the number of digits in the product 4*51*6001*70001*800001*9000001? I know the basic technique is to factor out tens, but I would like to know some details about this method. Thank you all!

Comment: Have you considered expressing the number as a power of 10, I.E X = 10^n, and then consider the base 10 logarithm of both sides?

Comment: Yes, but how about not using the calculator?

Comment: Thanks! I understand know.

Comment: No problem! I've turned my comment into an answer so that others can take note of it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case, you should consider the base 10 logarithm of the number. It should be easy to simplify things since $\log_{10}{ab} = \log_{10}{a} + \log_{10}{b}$.

But since calculators are not allowed for your specific example, we'll have to do it a bit differently. The product in your specific example is roughly equals to $4 \times 50 \times 6000 \times 70000 \times 800000 \times 9000000$. I guess its easier to calculate the number of digits from here on, and probably the only way (AFAIK) to do it without a calculator for your specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$[\log_{10}(\cdot)]$$ of it.