# Determine the number of digits of the product a.b

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

If $ a = 3,643,712,546,890,623,517 $ and $ b = 179,563,128 $, determine the number of digits of the product $ a.b $. I went searching the site and found this post where advise to use logarithm [Calculate the number of digits in a product of large numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644889/calculate-the-number-of-digits-in-a-product-of-large-numbers)
But I am looking for something simpler. I did

$ 3.10^{18} <u = 3 ... <3,7.10^{18} $ and $ 10^8 <v = 179 ... <2.10^8 $

$$ 3.10^{26} <u.v <7,4.10^{26} $$ so that's 27 digits. Would this be right? Is there a more specific way to solve?

Comment: Why did you change from $a,b$ to $u,v?$  Also please do not use periods for multiplication, use \cdot to get a centered dot.  Periods look like decimal points.

Comment: Also, please use periods not commas for decimals (see 3,7 or 7,4) as those are clearer. (No one peer reviewed my edit.......)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, and what you did is perhaps a more intuitive way of the logarithm-based method.

When you say $a$ has 19 digits, you are inherently saying its logarithm is $18.xxx$, and similarly for $b=8.yyy$. Thus $ab$ has either $27$ or $28$ digits ($\log_{10}ab=26+z$ where $z<2$), but when you upper-bound both numbers and show that the product of the first digits is less than $10$, you are inherently saying that $.xxx+.yyy<1$, i.e. the numbers are not big enough to introduce an additional digit. Hence there are $27$ digits.